# How to switch between document tabs in AvalonDock 2

Tags: c#, avalondock

I have build a little app that uses AvalonDock 2.  I bound my view models to the docking manager, can create and remove documents, all fine.  However, there is one thing I do net get to work:  When I have multiple documents open I am not able to make a specific document tab the active and visible tab (like if I would click on the tab header) from code.

I have bound to the "ActiveContent" property and set it to the document I want to be the active and visible one, but that does not help.

Can please someone give me some advice on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research it turned out to be a trivial task.  The actual problem is lack of documentation on such trivial tasks.  So here for all others who fight with the same problem, the answer:

Each *LayoutItem* has a property named `IsSelected`.  By setting its value to 'true', the tab representing the *LayoutItem* is switched into view.

Comment: Andreas, this is a helpful pointer, but It'd be great if you could provide an example (given the official documentation is light on this).

Otherwise it's only half of an answer.

Comment: @CJBrew: Well, to be honest, setting a Property on an object to a value should not require a sample.  Maybe you can explain, what kind of sample you would like to see.

Comment: Of course setting a property statically in the xaml is trivial. In this context though: which control is the `LayoutItem`? How would you bind that property to the viewmodel?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non MMVM solution to making a Layout the active or selected layout in AvalonDock 2.

Code below written in the same class as your XAML MainWindow where "mainPanel" is the name of your LayoutDocumentPane.

XAML

```
<xcad:LayoutDocumentPane x:Name="mainPanel">
```

Code Behind:

```
public void MakeActiveLayout(String layoutTitle)
{
    foreach (LayoutDocument child in mainPanel.Children)
    {
        if(child.Title == layoutTitle)
        {
            child.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined the DockingManager in XAML like this:

```
<xcad:DockingManager Name="dockingManager"/>
```

You can set the selected document tab in code behind with this:

```
// Gets the main LayoutDocumentPane of the DockingManager 
var documentPane = this.dockingManager.Layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutDocumentPane>().FirstOrDefault();

if (documentPane != null)
{
    foreach (LayoutDocument child in documentPane.Children)
    {
        if (child.Content.GetType() != typeof(MyView))
        {
            child.IsSelected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```